# XPath errors on empty link element

Tags: css, xpath, hyperlink, element

I'm new to xpath and trying to extract from the header element in the code provided:

```
<div class="description" itemprop="description">
      <link id="tabscss" rel="stylesheet" onError="jQuery191('#tabs > ul > li').hide();>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                                   <a href="#tabs-1">WTF</a>
                             </li>
             </ul>
            <div class="description" id="tabs" itemprop="description">
             <ul>
                 <li>
                                   <a href="#tabs-1">Description</a>
                             </li>
             </ul>
             <div id="tabs-1">
                 <h1>6 units/lot</h1>
                 <h1>($ 3.25/unit)</h1>
                 <p>Brings 2 liquid matte Gloss , 3 Matte lipsticks &amp; a Bonus Matte lip liner </p>
                 <p>Brings beauty guide for the perfect look </p>
                 <p><strong>**We can not guarantee the condition of any acrylic displays as they are extremely delicate and may get damaged during its delivery.**</strong></p>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the following:

```
//div[@class='description']//div[@id='tabs-1']/h1[1]
```

to extract the content of the header (h1[1]) element. I always get an empty result, EXCEPT if I remove the link element OR add a closing / to the link element.

It appears the link element redirects the xpath query and doesn't allow it to parse the rest of the request.

What I've read on link elements does provide an answer as to how to either avoid the link element or escape it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you should close `">` your link element:

Change:

`<link id="tabscss" rel="stylesheet" onError="jQuery191('#tabs > ul > li').hide();>`

to

`<link id="tabscss" rel="stylesheet" onError="jQuery191('#tabs > ul > li').hide();">`